# Linux - where is the binary file I built in vs code

Tags: c#, .net, linux, bash, visual-studio-code

I have a C# project made in VS Code on Linux. While debugging I didn't have any issues with binaries or whatsoever but when I finished all the tests and wanted to run the program from terminal it turned out I dont know where to find.

The only solution I found was
`cd project_folder dotnet run project_name`
Is there any other way to do it? I want to make a single binary file that could be run from terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process of creating a single file executable is explained at [Single-file deployment and executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli).

You will need to add some settings into your csproj file, for example:

> ```
> <PropertyGroup>
>     <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
>     <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
>     <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
>     <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
>     <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
>     <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
>   </PropertyGroup>
> ```

...

> These properties have the following functions:
>
> - `PublishSingleFile`. Enables single file publishing. Also enables single file warnings during dotnet build.
> - `SelfContained`. Determines whether the app is self-contained or framework-dependent.
> - `RuntimeIdentifier`. Specifies the OS and CPU type you're targeting. Also sets `<SelfContained>true</SelfContained>` by default.
> - `PublishReadyToRun`. Enables ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation.

With these settings set you can run `dotnet publish`.

---

You can also specify these settings to the publish command without adding them to the project file. For example:

> `dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained false`

Comment: For Linux it would be then `<RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>`